# CSS3 for Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, css

I have installed Service Pack 1 for Visual Studio 2010. I get the HTML 5 option in the Target Schema for Validation, but when I open a .css file to change the CSS Version for Validation, I don't have an option for CSS 3. I'm new to ASP.Net and have no idea why this isn't there? I assumed (from research) that installing SP1 would give me this option?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to install `CSS 3 Intellisense Schema` from Visual Studio gallery. Please use this link to download: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7211bcac-091b-4a32-be2d-e797be0db210